# CardView adjust length and width to fit screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-cardview

In my application, i am using CardView UI elements. I have two CardView elements which i want to display in UI. Here is the code what i have.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/display_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#1976D2"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/display_information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/display_image"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#1976D2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the ViewHolder & Adpater class which i am using.

```
    public class DisplayItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DisplayItemViewHolders> {

    private List<DisplayItemInformation> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public DisplayItemRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<DisplayItemInformation> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public DisplayItemViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.display_card, parent, false);
        layoutView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        DisplayItemViewHolders rcv = new DisplayItemViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DisplayItemViewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        holder.image.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }
}


public class DisplayItemViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView name;
    public TextView detailedInformation;
    public ImageView image;

    //private final Context context;

    public DisplayItemViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        //context = itemView.getActivity();

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), importantDatesDashboardActivity.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "New ACTIVITY started 111 = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

In above code, I want to adjust the width and height of the two Cards to fit the screen? How i can adjust the width & height for the cards and display the cards vertically? Point to note here is the images which are shown inside Cards are bigger than screen size.

Thanks in advance,
*IamHuM*

Comment: Will you always just have 2 cards? You're using a RecyclerView which is meant to display a large and potentially changing list of elements. If you only have two cards I would suggest not using a RecyclerView.

Comment: Yes mostly i will have two elements only. So if not RecyclerView then what i should use instead of RecyclerView?

Comment: So if you only ever have two elements, I'd just put both elements in a LinearLayout using layout weights to have each element take up 50% of the screen. Here's the docs about how layout weight works: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight --- basically you can put your CardViews inside of a LinearLayout (consider using the include tag). Then set the same weight number on each of your CardViews and they will each take up 50% of the screen.

Comment: And if you sometimes have more than 2 cards, you'd need to know how many cards and what you want them to look like on screen